# Connect to Linux File System with default "Connect to Server"?

Tags: macos, webserver

I'm wondering what kind of setup I need on my Linux machine to be able to connect to it using the default "Connect to Server" (command + k) in OSX. I'm going to ask this on askubuntu as well, but I want to see if anyone here knows the server connection types that the default file connections in OSX are?

I only want to change my server setup, not install anything new on my OSX machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up either nfs, samba, or netatalk. You can then connect with `nfs://`, `smb://` (or `cifs://`) or `afp://` respectively.

You can also run `avahi` for to have your server show up automatically in the Finder via Bonjour.

Comment: I already installed netatalk and it works exactly like I wanted with afp. thanks!